# Embed pdf into iframe with pdf.js,viewer.html and viewer.js not working in Firefox and IE

Tags: javascript, pdf, iframe, pdf.js

I am using following code to embed pdf into iframe using pdf.js. Its working fine in Chrome but not working in Firefox and IE.

```
var accessToken = 'abcd';  
 if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
     // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
     request = new XMLHttpRequest();
}
else {
     // code for IE6, IE5
     request = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}
request.open("GET", "https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/fileid?alt=media", true); 
request.setRequestHeader('Authorization','Bearer '+accessToken);    
request.responseType = "blob";
request.send();  
console.log(request.response);
request.onload = function (e) {
if (this.status === 200) {
    // `blob` response
  console.log(this.response);        
  // create `objectURL` of `this.response` : `.pdf` as `Blob`
  var file = window.URL.createObjectURL(this.response);   
  var viewerUrl = 'test.html?file=' + encodeURIComponent(file);    
  document.write('<iframe id="showskill" frameborder="0" scrolling="yes" 
 seamless="seamless" style="display:block; width:100%; height:100vh;" 
 src='+viewerUrl+'></iframe>');
 };
 };
```

Comment: Why do you `request.send();` two times?

Comment: Written by mistake, Updated now.